# Tire sidewall cut. Thoughts?Replace?

Tags: tires, sidewall-damage

**(UPDATE):** I replaced both tires. Since 1 was in perfect conditions I kept them in my garage. Thanks for the comments.

So I hit this curb yesterday at night and today I checked and has a cut on the tire. I wasn't planning on replacing it but after pulling a bit I can see that part inside. Is it bad:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I see metal.  You're [unfortunately] done.  Replace it.

Comment: @SteveRacer those are the body plies of the tire. They are usually made of polyester, and unlikely to be metal. That said, yes, replace.

Comment: @marcelm Heard.  I'm a big truck guy, so I mis-typed.  I see *shiny* cords.  Bad it is.  Tire replace you must.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change that - the plies are exposed and there may be other delamination that you cannot see.

Comment: _Have to_ is a bit extreme. _Would recommend_ changing it it if at all possible, but if you're broke it'll probably last a while. It's not safe, but neither is life. If you can't change it immediately, put it on the rear wheel so if it blows you won't loose control of the vehicle.

Comment: Mike is correct, this requires replacement. If this car is out if control it will create havoc for surrounding pedestrian, vehicles, and property. If anyone found this post, they can sue him for negligence

Comment: Not to mention that *when* it fails it's going to be a royal pain, perhaps destroying a rim, wheel well, body damage,  and requiring a tow.  Not worth trifling with.  It may leak air slowly now, even exacerbating the potential for blowout. In many jurisdictions you won't pass inspection, either.  Not worth trying to buy yourself maybe 6-9 months.

Answer (score -1):

Replacement is necessary.

In case of RWD/FWD change a pair of accompanying tires on that axle.
For AWD/4WD change all 4. Since the drive terrain requires a specific and equal grip on the wheel pushing/pulling tires.

Comment: Whoever added the negative 2 score, the Question poster, replaced a set of tires on this car.

Answer (score -2):

Replace as soon as possible. They will probably fail when you least expect it. They are cheap, replace them now.

Comment: Again a minus 2 score here, unfair to downgrade this advice. If our answers are not good recommend edits.